# Pyrebase uploaded image not loading firebase storage

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, pyrebase

I'm not able to make this work, I want to upload a picture to firebase with pyrebase and the file(picture) goes through but it never loads on firebase/storage (see picture attached)

[image: Image from Firebase/Storage]

This is the code:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    upload = request.files['upload']
    upload.save(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename))
    storage.child("images/test.jpg").put(UPLOAD_FOLDER+filename)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last I heard, there is a bug in the Firebase console where images don't load if they were uploaded using one of the backend SDKs (as opposed to one of the Firebase client SDKs, or the Firebase console).  It uses the "access token" that you would see in the "File location" section for that file.  If there is no access token, the console won't know how to load the file.

If this is indeed the case for you, please [file a bug with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).  It's a known issue, but the report will let them know how many people are affected.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking `Create new access token` under `File Location` solves the issue.